# Using my own delegate

Tags: ios, delegates

I´m having problems declarating my own delegate. Well...thats not exactly true: i have it declarated and, when i build the project, the compiler reports no issues. I declarated it in this way:

I made a file (enviarDatos.h) for declare the protocol:

```
@protocol enviarDatos <NSObject>
    - (void)addItemViewController:(NSMutableArray *)item;
@end
```

In the Vista2.h (ViewController) file I imported the file enviarDatos.h and declared a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <enviarDatos> delegare;
```

In the Vista2.m (ViewController) file I use the protocol method:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <enviarDatos> {
```

And, finally, in the ViewController.m file I implement the delegates method:

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(NSMutableArray *)ar {
   origen = ar; 
}
```

Does anyone see something wrong? the code of the last function its never executing.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

What i need is to change an array in ViewController from Vista2 (another viewcontroller)

Comment: What errors are you getting?  What problems are you having? These will help us to help you.

Comment: Well, are you ever calling the method?

Comment: In `vista2.h` you've to add `delegate=self;` and implement the `delegate method` then only it will call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Then create delegate property in next view(child view) & set it to self in parent view while pushing or showing child view.

ParentView.m
1.Implement protocol methods
- (void)addItemViewController:(NSMutableArray *)ar
{
    origen = ar; 
}

2.While showing child view
ChildViewController *child = [[ChildViewController alloc] init];
child.delegate = self;
//present child view

ChildView.h
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <enviarDatos> delegare;

 ChildView.m
-(void) anyMethod
{
 if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addItemViewController:)])
    {
        [self.delegate addItemViewController:mutableArray];
    }
}
```

Comment: i want send data to a previous view. I know how to send data to the next view. Now i want make it with a delegate

Comment: Tell me which is your previous view & next view.

Comment: call me idiot but what have i to do for call the method from the ChildViewController?

Comment: really thanks!! now the method its executing. Now, i think, i understand how to manage created protocols :)

Comment: You should accept this answer, if it resolved your problem. So that others will know that you got answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it looks like you are declaring the delegate property in the wrong place.

You should declare the property delegate in enviarDatos.h.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <enviarDatos> delegate;
```

Then in Vista2.m you will do something like this...

```
EnviarDatos *myObject = [[EnviarDatos alloc] init];
myObject.delegate = self;
```

This then sets up the EnviarDatos object and assigns the Vista2 object as the delegate.

Now, in EnviarDatos.m you can run...

```
[self.delegate addItemViewController:someObjectArray];
```

And this will then run that code in the Vista2 object.

Delegates are used for calling back to objects that create them (or some other objects).  If you create an object and then want to run a method in it then you won't need a delegate.

Comment: thanks for the solution but i cant instantiate the delegate. xCode tells me that its wrong

Comment: Where are you trying to instantiate it. The delegate property belongs to the enviarDatos not Vista2. You need to make sure that is in the correct place.  Also, I would change the protocol to be <enviarDatosDelegate> to avoid confusion.

Comment: i mean: as u told me, i created the property in enviarDatos.h, but i cant instantiate it in vista2.m (i imported the file)

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you say at what condition `addItemViewController` is invoked?
2. You seem to be on the right track, but are you sure you are setting the delegate as

   ```
   [yourObject setDelegate: self];
   ```
3. Have you tried debugging it? Does the debugger pause at `addItemViewController` if you set a breakpoint there? Can you confirm the delegate is not null inside the method? I may post some code but your seems to be right except for the assigning of delegate, I think you should check it.

Comment: 1) i thought i was calling it before changing view.
2) i cant instantiate the delegate
3) im going to check it.
Sorry, im new on this